# Carthage framework target can't find dependencies

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, carthage

I've created a library, which I would like to distribute via CocoaPods and Carthage.

I can't get my shared framework target to build with Carthage, I get a build error, basically stating it can't find Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, which are dependencies of my framework. I've added SwiftyJSON and Alamofire to my Cartfile and to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section of my shared framework target.

If I run Pod install first everything works fine, presumably because CocoaPods makes my dependencies available, but obviously this is not a good solution.